# Personalize titles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I need to change the aspect of the chapter's title.
I tryed tikz, using this other thread:
[Is there is a package so you can add text with visual effects like "WordArt" from "Word"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85863/is-there-is-a-package-so-you-can-add-text-with-visual-effects-like-wordart-fro)

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\flushleft\normalfont}
{} {20pt}
{%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikz]
 \node at (-14,-3) [text=transparent!20]
 {\fontfamily{ptm}\Huge\selectfont\textbf{\textsc{#1}}  };
 \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[path fading=tikz,fit fading=false,
left color=red,right color=orange]
 (-7,-1) rectangle (8,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
          }
\begin{document}
\chapter{Not so long title}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Very very very very loooong title-Centered}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

But it's not aligned with the text, it's centered instead.
How can I align it to the left?
Can I also put the tikz title into a `tcolorbox`? I wanted a frame and the number..

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve actually, but perhaps this is similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248123/how-to-create-partial-borders-around-section-titles. You can use `tikz` code in the `overlay` feature of `tcolorbox`

Comment: Do you want it centred relative to the width of the text block rather than the page width?

Comment: I played with your code but I can't figure out what you want it to do.

Comment: No, I want the title on the left, such that the abscissa where the normal text and the title starts would be the same for both.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, I'll try (not sure of results). Thank you!

Comment: I tried, but with no results..! I mean, the are no errors, but it's still centered. There's a way I can use x/yshift? I can't move the title..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chapter titles are actually aligned left --- the left side of the rectangle `(-7,-1) rectangle (8,1)` touches the left border of the text area. To see this, one may delete `path fading=tikz` to get

[image]

So the solution is to make a rectangle that fits the title. Perhaps the best way is to do everything again, *transparently*.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\flushleft\normalfont}{}{20pt}
{
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikz]
        \node[text width=20cm,text=transparent!20]
        {\fontfamily{ptm}\Huge\selectfont\textbf{\textsc{#1}}\\};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=20cm,text opacity=0,shade,path fading=tikz,fit fading=false,left color=red,right color=orange]
        {\fontfamily{ptm}\Huge\selectfont\textbf{\textsc{#1}}\\};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

So one has

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: I think I can fix the problem with tcolorbox, and insert the number, so that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!!